# How to parse a string format like [***]***?

Tags: objective-c

I need to parse a string like `[abc]000`, and what I want to get is an array containing `abc` and `000`. Is there an easy way to do it?

I'm using code like this:

```
NSString *sampleString = @"[abc]000";
NSArray *sampleParts = [sampleString componentsSeparatedByString:@"]"];
NSString *firstPart = [[[sampleParts objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"["] lastObject];
NSString *lastPart = [sampleParts lastObject];
```

But it's inefficient and didn't check whether the string is in a format like [**]**.

Comment: [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Did any of our answers help you with this?

Answer (score 1):

For this simple pattern, can just parse yourself like:

```
NSString *s = @"[abc]000";
NSString *firstPart = nil;
NSString *lastPart = nil;
if ([s characterAtIndex: 0] == '[') {
    NSUInteger i = [s rangeOfString:@"]"].location;
    if (i != NSNotFound) {
        firstPart = [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, i - 1)];
        lastPart = [s substringFromIndex:i + 1];
    }
}
```

Or you could learn to use the NSScanner class.

Answer (score 1):

As always, there are lots of ways to do this.

**OPTION 1**
If these are fixed length strings (each part is always three characters) then you can simply get the substrings directly:

```
NSString *sampleString = @"[abc]000";
NSString *left = [sampleString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 3)];
NSString *right = [sampleString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 3)];
NSArray *parts = @[ left, right ];
NSLog(@"%@", parts);
```

**OPTION 1 (shortened)**

```
NSArray *parts = @[ [sampleString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 3)],
                    [sampleString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 3)] ];
NSLog(@"%@", parts);
```

**OPTION 2**
If they aren't always three characters, then you can use `NSScanner`:

```
NSString *sampleString = @"[abc]000";

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:sampleString];

// Skip the first character if we know that it will always start with the '['.
// If we can not make this assumption, then we would scan for the bracket instead.
scanner.scanLocation = 1;

NSString *left, *right;

// Save the characters until the right bracket into a string which we store in left.
[scanner scanUpToString:@"]" intoString:&left];

// Skip the right bracket
scanner.scanLocation++;

// Scan to the end (You can use any string for the scanUpToString that doesn't actually exist...
[scanner scanUpToString:@"\0" intoString:&right];

NSArray *parts = @[ left, right ];
NSLog(@"%@", parts);
```

**RESULTS (for all options)**

```
2013-05-10 00:25:02.031 Testing App[41906:11f03] (
    abc,
    000
)
```

**NOTE**
All of these assume well-formed strings, so you should include your own error checking.

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

```
NSString *sampleString = @"[abc]000";
NSString *pNRegex = @"\\[[a-z]{3}\\][0-9]{3}";
NSPredicate *PNTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pNRegex];
BOOL check=[PNTest evaluateWithObject:sampleString ];
NSLog(@"success:%i",check);
```

if `success` comes as 1 then you can perform the action for separating string into array.